# No rows fetching from stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have created a stored procedure like this, when I try to call it shows

```
call points;
$$
329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

What is the error in this stored procedure?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE POINTS()

    BEGIN    
        DECLARE NAMEEE VARCHAR(15);    
        declare monthcount int(10);    
        DECLARE CUR2 CURSOR for SELECT * FROM TEMP;    
        open CUR2;   
        read_loop: LOOP   
            FETCH CUR2  INTO NAMEEE;   
            select monthlycount into monthcount from incident  where name=NAMEEE;    
            if monthcount <= 3   then    
                UPDATE INCIDENT SET POINTS="10" WHERE NAME=NAMEEE;    
            elseif (monthcount > 3 and monthcount <=6) then    
                UPDATE INCIDENT SET POINTS="20" WHERE NAME=NAMEEE;   
            elseif (monthcount > 6 and monthcount <=9) then    
                UPDATE INCIDENT SET POINTS="30" WHERE NAME=NAMEEE;   
            elseif (monthcount >9 and monthcount <=12) then    
                UPDATE INCIDENT SET POINTS="40" WHERE NAME=NAMEEE;   
            elseif (monthcount >12 ) then    
                UPDATE INCIDENT SET POINTS="50" WHERE NAME=NAMEEE;    
            end if;   
        END LOOP;   
        CLOSE CUR2;   
    end $$
```

Here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INCIDENT(
NAME VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
DAILYCOUNT INT(10),
WEEKLYCOUNT INT(10),
MONTHLYCOUNT INT(10),
POINTS INT(10)  NOT NULL
);

insert into incident values("peter","1","2","3","0");
insert into incident values("thomas","1","2","4","0");
insert into incident values("franklins","1","2","6","0");
insert into incident values("yedhu","1","2","8","0");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP
(
NAME VARCHAR(15)
);

insert into  temp values("peter");
insert into  temp values("thomas");
insert into  temp values("franklins");
insert into  temp values("yedhu");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole stored procedure can be expressed using a single multi-table update statement. The update statement joins the 2 tables on name and name fields, and updates the points field based on the value in the monthcount field. `ceil()` effectively rounds up the results of the division. The `if()` function introduces the cap at 12.

```
update incident inner join temp on incident.name=temp.namee
set incident.points=if(incident.monthcount<=12,ceil(incident.monthcount / 3) * 10, 50)
```

So, you can avoid having a complicated stored procedure and replace it with a s

Comment: ceil(incident.monthcount / 3) * 10 , 50) please clarify this part

Comment: I explained the formula in the answer itself. Play around with it a little bit, try out different values in place of incident.monthcount if you have any further questions.

Comment: I can understand from your explanation, but why should we need to use () * 10 , 50)  , 50 in this formula?

Comment: Because that formula does what your complicated if structure does. No need for stored proc, just use a single multi table update statement.